# Matlab index error

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have coded an algorithm in MATLAB which contains a loop. The code works well for a number of iterations, then suddenly stops due to the following error

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

What could be the cause of this error?

This is part of the code.

```
[x,fval,exitflag,output]=cplexmilp(f,Aineq,bineq,Aeq,beq,sostype,sosind,soswt,lb,ub,ctype,x0,options)


for m=1:100
    supply=[];
    supply=x(1:p*w*t);
    supply=reshape(supply,w,p*t)';
    Failprob=[0.1927 0.1753 0.1728  0.1165 0.2375 0.1649];%Low
    %Failprob=[0.3770 0.3061 0.2894 0.2682 0.3993 0.2983];%Med
    Failprob=[0.5708 0.4842 0.4097 0.5144 0.4205 0.4312];%High
    %Failprob=[0.4547    0.4958    0.4965    0.4158    0.4971    0.4957];%High

    Epsilon=[.8 .9];%Low
    %Epsilon=[.7 .9];%Med
    Epsilon=[.6 .9];%High

    Sigma=.05;%Low
    %Sigma=.10;%Med
    Sigma=.2;%High

    Failprob=Failprob';
    prob2=1-Failprob;
    prob2=horzcat(prob2,Failprob);
    prob2=repmat(prob2,t,1);

    for n=1:t
        for i=1+p*(n-1):p+p*(n-1)            
            for j=1:w
                r=rand;
                prob=prob2(i,:);
                prob=cumsum(prob);
                value=[supply(i,j),(Epsilon(1)+(Epsilon(2)-Epsilon(1))*rand(1))*supply(i,j)];            
                %values corresponding to the probabilities
                ind=find(r<=prob,1,'first');
                supply(i,j)=value(ind);
            end
        end
    end
```

After some iterations, I have the following output.

```
Iteration 20 Current value 12020253.6911 Best value 12020253.6911
Iteration 21 Current value 10841341.9259 Best value 10841341.9259
Iteration 22 Current value 11307742.3543 Best value 10841341.9259
Iteration 23 Current value 10784746.9812 Best value 10784746.9812
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> CodefinalTwelveGuMulti at 1947
supply=x(1:p*w*t);
```

Comment: Please show some code as this question will likely be closed. The error message tells you exactly what is causing the error so show us what you wrote otherwise we can't help you with the information you provided. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Benoit_11 .. The code is very long .. can i send you via e-mail?

Comment: Well since this is a Q & A website that would be preferable to post a minimal example of your code that reproduces the error is it possible? Show only the relevant portion that creates the error.

Comment: @Benoit_11 I just posted .. Hope it helps

Comment: ok so it looks like the size of x is less than the product p*w*t; what are they? You can use whos to get information about variables in your script; that's easier to diagnose dimension problems.

Comment: Thank you very much @Benoit_11 ,but I really don't know what is the problem ..The exact same code works perfectly for small size problems, but when I have a larger size problem, It produce this problem. That is why I don't know why is this error.

Comment: Use the debugger to catch the error (`dbstop if error`), then inspect the sizes of all the variables in question, then continue debugging to figure out where the strange size came from.  Also possible: instead of debugging, just print the sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even know how that code could even run.  `x` is not defined anywhere and you suddenly are starting to use it in your `for` loop at the beginning.  My guess is that you have some code defined somewhere earlier on, those iterations start happening and then once those iterations end, this function runs.  That makes sense since I don't see any print-out statements anywhere in your code.

That's what the error is alluding to.  It is stating that you are trying to index into `x` with indices that exceed the dimensions of `x`.  In this case, `x` has no dimensions (i.e. empty).  As such, no matter what indices you are using to try to index into `x`, MATLAB will give you an index exceeding error.

You need to either define `x` by providing it as an input into your function, or define it inside the function itself.

Comment: Hello sir.. Yes as you said x is empty when the error occurs. Could you please advise me how to define x. I am not sure I understood what you mean.